# application.rb syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails5 api-only mode app.

My config/application.rb looks like this :

Added application.rb

```
  module Myapi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1



    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource (
          '*', 
          headers: :any, 
          methods: [:get, :patch, :put, :delete, :post, :options]
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require': 


ndflo-api/goforfloapi/config/application.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
          '*',
```

What's wrong with the syntax of line 38 that is causing this syntax error?

Line 38 looks like this :

```
'*',
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated to add question.

Comment: Maybe place explicit `()` around your calls and see if it persists? Possible interpreter getting confused? I don't personally see any syntax errors.

Comment: Whitespace is (sometimes) significant in Ruby. In particular, `m(a, b)` and `m (a, b)` are different: the parentheses in the first are method-calling parentheses, the second are interpreted as expression-grouping parentheses. And Ruby doesn't have a comma operator so `m (a, b)` is a syntax error. You want to say `resource(`, not `resource (`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you added parenthesis, remove the parenthesis and do not put new line `'*'` after `resource`  it should work:

It should be like this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :patch, :put, :delete, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, keep the parentheses, but do not add a space before opening one.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong here

Do this, tested.

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :patch, :put, :delete, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the resource line to make it a single-liner as follows :

```
resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :patch, :put, :delete, :post, :options]
```